# Optimizing Spark Operations (Count and Collect)

Tags: scala, optimization, apache-spark

I have two operations in my spark code that are taking the bulk of the computational time - The lines of code are

```
val d = x.map{case(x1,(x2,x3))=>(x2,x3)}.distinct.count.toDouble
```

which takes approximately 1.5 minutes on ~35 million rows of data. I have also tried using this command -

```
val d = x.map{case(x1,(x2,x3))=>(x2,x3)}.distinct.countApprox(timeout = 30, confidence = 0.95).
```

This does return the correct results in ~24 seconds. The result is -

```
res42: org.apache.spark.partial.PartialResult[org.apache.spark.partial.BoundedDouble] = (final: [8627.000, 8627.000])
```

which is correct but I do not know how to access this count to use in my calculations.

The second line of code is -

```
var num = y.values.toArray
```

which returns in ~ 1.6 minutes -

```
res46: Array[Double].
```

I use this Array to calculate -

```
y.map{case(k,v)=>(k,(num.filter(_<=v).length.toDouble/num.length.toDouble*100))}.
```

Is there a more efficient way to do these calculations? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE:**
I have found out how to use the approximate results of count -

```
x.map{case(x1,(x2,x3))=>((x2,x3),1)}.distinct.countApprox(30,0.95).getFinalValue.high.toDouble
```

**ADDED**

```
var s = x.map{case(x1,(x2,x3))=>((x1,x2,x3),1)}.reduceByKey(_+_).map{case((x1,x2,x3),x4)=>((x2,x3),(x1,x4))}.
    join(x.map{case(x1,(x2,x3))=>((x2,x3),1)}.reduceByKey(_+_)).map{case((x2,x3),((x1,x4),x5))=>
    (x1,(x4.toDouble/x5.toDouble*x3.toDouble, x3.toDouble))}

    var f = s.mapValues(_._1).reduceByKey(_+_).join(s.mapValues(_._2).reduceByKey(_+_)).map{case(k,v)=>(k,v._1/v._2)}

    val d = x.map{case(x1,(x2,x3))=>((x2,x3),1)}.distinct.countApprox(30,0.95).getFinalValue.high.toDouble

    var varietyFrac = x.distinct.mapValues(_=>1).reduceByKey(_+_).map{case(x1,x2)=>(x1,x2.toDouble/d)}

    var y = f.join(varietyFrac).map{case(name,(frac,varietyFrac))=>(name,pow((frac.toDouble*varietyFrac.toDouble),0.01)/0.01)}.persist
```

Comment: We seem to be missing some information. How many distinct values do you have from your 35 million rows? What is `y`? (an RDD, I assume). How many rows in `y`? How long does it take to do your calculation on `y`? How many different `v` values appear in `y`?

Comment: For the second line, you could sort y by the value of `v`, then iterate over the list - the index of the iteration is the same as `num.filter(_<=v).length`

Comment: @Paul - y.count yeilds 23518 rows and x.count is approximately 35 million rows. I added my code for the context. Thank you for your reply!